# in a PWA, is there a way to check for a waiting service worker upgrade?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I know that I can use the statechange to listen for the installed state and then prompt the user to see if they want to upgrade.

This works great as long as the user says YES right then. But when the user says no or for some reason hits the F5 to reload the page, there doesn't seem to be any way to check again to see if there is a waiting upgrade.

I am most interested in doing a quick check right after the page loads to see if there is a waiting upgrade and if need, re-prompt the user. The installed event doesn't fire on a page reload forcing the user to close the browser and open it again to get the upgrade installed. I feel that I must be missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to ask the ServiceWorkerRegistration about the waiting worker right after the registration process. What I got working for me was code like this...

**In the global scope of my script that registers the Service Worker I created a variable and function so I can hook into the new worker and prompt the user about the upgrade.**

```
var newWorker;

function promptToUpgrade()
{
    if(confirm('Upgrade to new version?'))
    {
        newWorker.postMessage("skipWaiting");
    }
}
```

**In the window.load function of the same script I store the connection to the waiting worker and if it is not NULL I call my prompt function.**

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js',{'scope':'./'}).then(function(reg) {
        newWorker=reg.waiting;
        if(newWorker) promptToUpgrade();
```

**In the Service Worker itself, I have several functions that the client might call to make the worker perform various tasks. One such task is to skipWaiting and activate the new worker. This example only shows the one task.**

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    switch(data)
    {
        case 'skipWaiting':
            self.skipWaiting();
            break;
    }
});
```

I also call the promptToUpdate function when the new worker is detected by adding a listener in the registration process for the **updatefound** event. That has been how I have done it all along. But this only fires when the new worker first installs and then never again. The code above allows me to check at the start of the registration process and then call the promptToUpdate again any time the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

service worker install event is emitted only when new service worker installed and activate event is emitted when installed service worker is activated.

```
self.addEventListener('install',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('install')
    localStorage.setItem('ServiceWorkerWaitingForInstall','true');
});

self.addEventListener('activate',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('activate')
    localStorage.setItem('ServiceWorkerWaitingForInstall','false');
});
```

You can check if new service worker waiting to be updated or not form By calling

```
    localStorage.getItem('ServiceWorkerWaitingForInstall');
```

Comment: This did let me know that a new worker was waiting, but it gave me no way to activate it. I came up with a solution that actually fit my needs.

Comment: you can use ServiceWorkerRegistration.update() to update the service worker

Comment: I wasn't trying to check for an update. The update has already been checked in my case and the user has been prompted once. But if the browser is left open and the user presses F5 to reload the page, the older service worker activates and the new one is still sitting in the "waiting" state. This will continue forever as long as the browser is left open. So until the user reboots or forces the browser close, they will not get the new version. This became a problem mainly on phones that hardly ever get powered off or get the browser cleared out of memory.

Comment: this artical might help you https://davidwalsh.name/service-worker-claim

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the process myself and accepted the answer above. When the SW registers, you can ask if there is a replacement upgrade waiting to take over.